# How do I add metadata to a file when uploading via a GCS signedUploadURL?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm using a signed URL (generated via the GCS PHP API) to upload a file to a bucket. I POST the signed URL, which returns a Location header which, in turn, I do a PUT of to do the actual upload. This basic upload process is working fine. Now, I need to pass some metadata (uploader name, uploader email, notes, etc.) along with the file.

According to the documentation, I add headers to the PUT request, of the form `'x-goog-meta-<name>': 'value'`, which are supposed to become the metadata. However, if I don't add them to the signed URL and the POST request, I get a spurious CORS error (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource).

The upload succeeds, and I can see in the Network tab of Chrome that these headers are getting added to the POST and PUT requests, but when the file hits the bucket, there is no metadata.

Here's my code, somewhat simplified:

```
var metadata, headers;

metadata =
{
  'sender-name':    "bob dobbs",
  'sender-email':   "bobdobbs@zynyz.com",
};

headers = { 'x-goog-resumable': 'start' };

for (var i in metadata)
{
  headers['x-goog-meta-' + i] = metadata[i];
}

// Start the upload
$.ajax(
{
  type:           POST,
  url:            signed_upload_url,
  success:        on_init_success,
  contentType:    file.type,
  headers:        headers,
  processData:    false
});

// Do the actual upload
var on_init_success = function(result, status, xhr)
{
  var loc;

  loc = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location');
  if (loc)
  {
      $.ajax(
      {
          type:           'PUT',
          url:            loc,
          data:           file,
          contentType:    file.type,
          headers:        headers,
          processData:    false
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you check within the cloud shell the metadata of your uploaded object, using this command “gsutil stat gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]” [1]

[1] -  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata

Comment: @andie: This shows no metadata, same as in the console.

Comment: Hi, You code looks fine, I think that the issue that you are facing could be better handled if you file a case  with GCP support in order to check why your bucket isn't received the metadata. 

https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

Comment: @andie: Sadly, we don't have a support plan, so I think SO is my only choice here. Thanks for checking the code, though. At least now I feel like I haven't done anything too dumb.